# Video.js basic setup and flash as primary tech

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I am still new to videojs and I am playing around with the most basic functionality.

I am not sure if the issues I have are problems with my setup, are they bugs that should be reported or I am simply doing it wrong.

First off even the demo at http://www.videojs.com/ when played has the option "show controls" in the dropdown menu. When clicked the player will show a second control bar along with the one that was already showing. Disabling "show controls" hides only the newly appeared control bar.

Is this a limitation to Video.JS that can't be avoided?

Basically I went to http://www.videojs.com/ , copied the code under "Embed this player" and changed the video source and poster to the ones hosted at videojs.com. Then I tried adding stuff to *data-setup* but I started getting some bizarre results

http://jsfiddle.net/a9uvasrh/1/

```
<video id="MY_VIDEO_2" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
preload="auto" width="640" height="264" autostart="false" poster="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg"
data-setup='{"techOrder": ["html5", "flash"}'>
<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type='video/webm'>
<p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

A player with empty data-setup has a big "Play" button that disappears when using the default values for techOrder and when I set techOrder to ["flash", "html5"] I expected to see videojs' flash player in action, but it still remains as html5.

My setup is Windows 7 with Flash Player 15. The problems persist in Chrome 38, Firefox 33, Opera 25, IE 11 (doesn't have the "show controls" option)

I am posting my question here in accordance with https://github.com/videojs/video.js/wiki/Support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Show controls' is part of the browser's native menu on video elements. Other than listening for a right click and blocking the context menu altogether, you can't remove that. In reality I doubt most end users would touch it.

Your JSON in `data-setup` is missing a closing bracket. It should be `{"techOrder": ["html5", "flash"]}`

Comment: Thank you, This was such a silly mistake. But what about [the flash player not running even with a correct syntax](http://jsfiddle.net/a9uvasrh/3/])?

Comment: See the [answer in your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26802873/740233)